# VScode/Python - Enable PEP8 Naming conventions

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pep8

I went through multiple SO questions but couldn't find a solution for my problem. I am new to Python and following is my setup,

```
VSCode: version 1.45
Python : 3.8.2
Pylint: 2.5.3
autopep8: 1.5.3
pycodestyle: 2.6.0
```

With the above setup, if I want to enforce [PEP8 naming conversions](https://github.com/PyCQA/pep8-naming) what should I do? The VScode documentation provide how to [configure pydocstyleargs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) but [it's documentation](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/2.1.1/error_codes.html) does not cover naming conventions.

I also looked at the things [autopep8 fixes](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8#features) and can configure via *"python.formatting.autopep8Args"*, it doesn't fix/report things like classes not having pascal-case

As mentioned by @PyWalker2797, I tried installing pep8 and enable it by setting *`"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true`*. But VSCode doesn't recognise it even after a restart of the application.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the [VSCode Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)?

Comment: Yes have version 2020.6.91350 installed.

Comment: It would be good if I know the reason for the down-vote!! Is it not clear, not useful or does not show research effort?

Comment: Is the setting available in the normal (graphical) Settings tab? Under "Extensions" there should be "Python" and that should contain a number of linting options. If it is, it should also auto-complete those options when you type them in the `settings.json` file. If you don't have it, it seems like there's something wrong with your VSCode installation and I would advise to reinstall VSCode and the Python extension.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

If you [read the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) you will notice that the setting is not called `pep8` but resides under the `pydocstyle` superset.

Thus, you have to use the following setting to enable checks on the variable conventions (and other stuff) from `pep8`:

`"python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,`

Answer (score 0):

Install `pep8` and `pylint` using `pip`:

```
pip install pep8
pip install pylint
```

Then get your `settings.json` file, and add the line:

```
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work.  VScode indicate it is a unknown configuration setting even after installing pep8(version 1.7.1). I updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: Did you install pep8 on the interpreter that vscode is currently using? Trying setting it up using a virtual environment.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve it either. Now I have pylint and pep8  installed in the venv. Still getting that 'unknown configuration' message.