# Adding pep8-naming to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint, pep8

I am trying to get PEP8-naming working on my VSCode (Version: 1.72.2 (Universal)) without luck.

I have `flake8`, `isort` and `mypy` enabled in my code and this all works as expected. I have installed pep8-naming (`conda install -c conda-forge pep8-naming`) and it shows in my flake8 version info:

```bash
flake8 --version
4.0.1 (mccabe: 0.7.0, naming: 0.13.2, pycodestyle: 2.8.0, pyflakes: 2.4.0) CPython 3.8.13 on Darwin
```

However, I am not seeing the errors for naming conventions showing in my VSCode editor.

I have the following set in my `settings.json` file

```json
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleArgs": ["--max-line-length=120"]
}
```

What am I missing so as to be able to see (for instance) that variables are named in Camel case rather than lower case with underscores?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62908588/vscode-python-enable-pep8-naming-conventions) without any luck.